# DIV element in chrome and internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I am getting defferent alignment with Google Chrome and Internet Explorer when I use DIV element to divide my web page into different blocks.

Is There anything different with Chrome and I.E. for using CSS properties for Div tag alignment.

Comment: Need some code to help at all.

Comment: have you tried a css reset to reset the browser default styles?

Comment: Yes, depending on the Doctype and whether IE is in Compatability View mode, there can be a huge difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are incredibly obvious differences depending on what version of `IE` you are using.

A quick margin/padding fix would be to place this on top of your `css`:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

A more thorough fix would be to include [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)